# openstack installation with devstack fails

Tags: openstack

DevStack is a series of extensible scripts used to quickly bring up a complete OpenStack environment based on the latest versions of everything from git master.

I am running the command `./stack.sh`

openstack installation with devstack fails. The error message is as below:

> nova-compute no process found.

Comment: Please add some more information like logs, local.conf file ?